# Commercial 2D game engines?

Tags: 2d

I know that there are several open-source/free 2D game engines out there; I am just wondering about commercial ones (if any). The idea of wanting of looking for a commercial engine is for support and continual updates.

Off the bat I know that there is DarkBasic, Blitz Basic and Torque 2D. What's else are there?

What I am looking for (technical wise):

- Sprites and Animation capability
- GUI (menus, dialogs, simple controls)
- Math helper for usual math operations -vectors, rotation, turning an entity to face another...
- Entity management
- Particles
- Serialization of game data
- Level design tools
- Deployment tools

And support wise

- Documentation
- Examples and Tutorials
- Continual update
- Support through forum/emails/private channels

Comment: Converted this to CW.

Comment: Also for list-type questions, it's usually better to put your examples as answers instead of built into the question, that way there's a singular place for people to comment/vote on each of those.

Comment: "Commerical" -> "Commercial" on title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are the ones I know of which are commercial and 2D, at least primarily. Pushbutton is an edge case, since the engine is free but components cost money. If you take that into account, I guess a few more engines could be seen as commercial if you count the byproducts that are being sold. Cocos2D for iPhone would be an example for that, or SIO2 Interactive.

- [Corona Game Edition](http://anscamobile.com/corona) (Lua) iOS & Android
- [Kanji 2D Game Engine](http://www.kanjiengine.com/cms/) (Win, Mac, iOS)
- [PushButton Engine](http://pushbuttonengine.com/) (Flash) Only components are commercial.
- [DragonFire SDK](http://www.dragonfiresdk.com/index.htm) (iOS Development
  in Windows)
- [GameSalad](http://www.gamesalad.com) Game Creator for iOS
- [Stencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/) Game Creator for Flixel
- [The Games Factory 2](http://www.clickteam.com/website/usa/the-games-factory-2.html) Game Creator
- [Game Maker 8](http://www.yoyogames.com/gamemaker/) Game Creator
- [Game Editor](http://game-editor.com/Main_Page) Game Creator

Plus all the other, specialized Game Creators. For example for RPGs, Adventures, Shoot'em Ups, Jump'n Runs, etc ...

Comment: I'm not sure but aren't Game Maker and Game Maker Studio two different things?

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on what are your needs. I dont know about DarkBasic and Blitz Basic but for Torque2D, depending on your experience you will encounter some "weird" situations because TorqueScript is not the type of language we are really used to use. First of all it's a scripting language, and maybe it is what you need but maybe not.

I Sugest you take a look on this list : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines

As it's seems quite complete. Maybe you could tell us what are your specific needs ? This way we could sugest some engines.

Comment: Have edited the question.

Comment: Maybe you could have a nice engine with some side librairies such as boost for math, serialization, etc ?